# Apple Photos Favourite export using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, apple-photos

I am trying to find a way to do the following export

Current structure
Honeymoon
County
   City
     Album

I want to export the structure to say my pictures folder as

Honeymoon > County > City > Album > photo names

But I only want to choose the photos which have been edited (normally favourited)

I have found an AppleScript which will allow me to choose an album and export its contents

```
set dest to "/Users/adammann/Pictures/HoneymoonExports" as POSIX file as text -- the destination folder (use a valid path)
tell application "Photos"
  activate
  set l to name of albums
  set albNames to choose from list l with prompt "Select some albums" with multiple selections allowed
  if albNames is not false then -- not cancelled
  repeat with tName in albNames
  set tFolder to dest & tName
  my makeFolder(tFolder) -- create a folder named (the name of this album) in dest 
  export (get media items of album tName) to (tFolder as alias) without using originals
  end repeat
  end if
end tell
on makeFolder(tPath)
  do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of tPath
end makeFolder
```

But I am unable to get it to only export the "Favorite" ones it just exports all.

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction I would be greatful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just use a filter:

```
export (get media items of album tName whose favorite is true) to (tFolder as alias) without using originals
```

Comment: Thanx. I'll try it out and let you know.